# Drools Rule Matching Behavior - Evaluation of Multiple Objects in a Collection

Tags: java, drools

I am working with a Drools rule in which I have the following pattern matching conditions:

```
when
$contract: ContractFact()
$entity: EntityFact
$service: ServiceFact(serviceId == $contract.serviceId) from $contract.services
$ec: EvaluationCriteriaFact(
    toCode contains $entity.toCodes,
    fromCode contains $entity.fromCodes,
) from $service.evaluationCriterias

$pricing: Pricing(($entity.Weight >= minWeight && $entity.Weight <= maxWeight)) from 
$ec.pricingscenarios
$priceResult: PricingResultObject()
then
$priceResult.price = $calculatePrice.getTowPriceG($entity.toCodes, ...)
end
```

`

My concern is regarding the behavior when one of the EvaluationCriteriaFact instances matches the conditions but fails to match the Pricing conditions ($entity.Weight >= minWeight && $entity.Weight <= maxWeight). In this case, does the Drools engine proceed to check the remaining objects present in the evaluationCriterias list, or does it stop evaluating further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule will fire once for each object in the list that matches your criteria. Each element in the list will be considered individually.

Here's a simpler example.

```
rule "example"
when
  Event( $attendees: attendees ) 
  Person( isVegetarian == true, $name: name ) from $attendees
then
  System.out.Println($name + " is attending and requires a vegetarian meal.")
end
```

If we pass the following object:

```
{
  attendees: [
    { name: "Alice", isVegetarian: true },
    { name: "Bob", isVegetarian: false },
    { name: "Charlie", isVegetarian: true },
    { name: "Denise" isVegetarian: false }
  ]
}
```

Then the output would be (in some order):

```
Alice is attending and requires a vegetarian meal.
Charlie is attending and requires a vegetarian meal.
```

If you invoked the rules using `fireAllRules`, that method would return 2 because the same rule matched and executed twice, once for the 'Alice' person, and once for the 'Charlie' person.

Comment: Is there any way such that we can stop the execution for remaining objects in the list after finding a one object which matches the criteria?

Comment: Use `exists`, which only checks for a match existing rather than extracting it.

Comment: In the above code snippet, If "ec" is found and pricing is not found, then it checks another object from evaluationCriterias. If both are found, it returns that result without checking the remaining ones. Is this a expected behavior?

Comment: Every item in evaluationCriterias is considered independently.